# Why I listen two different pronunciations of the word "alfil"?

Tags: pronunciación, acentuación

I started to play chess with a couple of Mexican friends. Since I don't play very well, they recommended me some videos of Spanish-speaker YouTubers to learn chess and something of Spanish at the same time. I thought the correct pronunciation of *alfil* was *al**fil***, stressing the last syllable because that is the way I've always listened. But I've noticed that some people from Spain pronounce ***al**fil*, rather stressing on the first syllable. For example: [1](https://youtu.be/k0BvxNlHNLg?feature=shared&t=103) [2](https://youtu.be/k0BvxNlHNLg?feature=shared&t=673) [3](https://youtu.be/2eLIOvyHjwQ?feature=shared&t=296) [4](https://youtu.be/2eLIOvyHjwQ?feature=shared&t=389).

If I didn't listen wrong, is this pronunciation of the word a common practice? Is it considered wrong? Did you ever hear that? My hypothesis is that comes from another language such as Catalan, Galician, Asturian, etc. but I couldn't find anything.

Comment: According to the rules governing stress usage in Spanish, the correct pronunciation is "al**fil**". For "**al**fil" to be said, there should be a written stress on "a", because it would be a word stressed on its penultimate syllable and not ending in "n", "s" or a vowel, such as "mástil", "hábil", "dócil".

Comment: @Gustavson But it seems some people pronunce it different, so I want to be sure if the fact that I listened "**al**fil" from two different YouTubers is something "regional" or it is a mere coincidence

Comment: Yes, I understood your question but don't know the answer, that's why I simply made a comment. There are some words that are mispronounced by some people, due to cultural or regional questions, and this seems to be the case.

Comment: Incidentally you mean hear (=oír) not listen (=escuchar)

Answer (score 3):

I agree with Gustavson that it's difficult to answer this question ... Just for completeness, let me add a screenshot of the RAE Community Manager addressing the same topic in Twitter

[image: RAE saying that alfil is aguda]

So according to that tweet the correct pronunciation is al**fil** but I've also heard **al**fil. Being a relatively specialised term probably how you pronounce it depends on how it was pronounced by the one that taught you how to play chess.